# Can Shapiro Time Delay cause light in a vacuum to go faster than c as viewed from a remote reference frame?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, time-dilation

I know within any reference frame the speed of light is fixed. But it has been shown that light does appear to slow down when passing massive objects as viewed from a remote reference frame per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro_time_delay.

My question is if, when light is passing through large voids in space, at lower gravitational potentials than we have here on earth, if we would measure that light as going faster than C from our reference frame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know within any reference frame the speed of light is fixed.

You need to be careful with such statements. The correct statement is: in any **inertial** frame the speed of light in vacuum is c.

When spacetime is curved there are no global inertial frames, only local ones which cover a small enough region of spacetime that curvature can be neglected. In each of those local frames light travels at c. When looking at large reference frames, which are necessarily non-inertial, it is easy to find examples where the speed of light in vacuum is larger or smaller than c.

Answer (score 0):

General relativity doesn't have global frames of reference. There is no meaningful notion of measuring the speed of light in the kind of context you're talking about, where spacetime is curved.

An answer by Dale says: "When looking at large reference frames, which are necessarily non-inertial, it is easy to find examples where the speed of light in vacuum is larger or smaller than c." This is wrong. GR doesn't have any notion of an inertial or noninertial global frame of reference.

Comment: You may want to read about tetrads. Those are often considered to be reference frames, and can certainly be global and classified as inertial or non-inertial