# Is G.R. internally inconsistent due to Shapiro Time Delay?

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation

An axiom of G.R. is that the speed of light is constant in all inertial reference frames.  Is it possible to construct an inertial reference frame where the speed of light would not be constant due to Shapiro Time Delay?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/725167/can-shapiro-time-delay-cause-light-in-a-vacuum-to-go-faster-than-c-as-viewed-fro?rq=1

Comment: Not sure why you linked my earlier question...

Comment: did you understand the answer by Dale to you previous question? *When looking at large reference frames, which are necessarily non-inertial* , GR is a large reference frame

Comment: @annav so I guess what is wrong with my question / understanding is that inertial reference frames are limited to special relativity and don't exist in G.R.?

Comment: they exist locally, for small dimensions and energies as the answer explains

Comment: @annav  It isn't straight forward how to translate 'locally' or 'small dimensions and energies' into comprehension.  When is something local enough to qualify?  What is too large of a dimension or energy?  Any answer that raises more questions than it answers isn't really any answer IMO.  It doesn't help me know if an inertial frame exists that encapsulates Shapiro time delay for example.

Comment: For a physicist or one studying physics I do not think there should be a problem ,You better  delve in some mathematics if you are so concerned. Physics cannot be understood with just words. To see the complexity of the subject see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252061080_Shapiro_Time_Delay_within_the_Geolocation_Problem_by_TDOA

Comment: @annav you are just gatekeeping.  Why even come on here to answer questions if your goal is to only help those who don't need help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. We interpret Shapiro delay as the light taking a longer path through curved spacetime than it would through flat spacetime. It still moves at the speed of light along that path.

Comment: What about the opposite scenario when light goes through a lower gravitational potential and appears to run faster than c to the observer?

Comment: @HardlyCurious You mean as in the differing delays in multiple gravitationally lensed images? Our interpretation is that light travels at the speed of light through each path, but because the geometry is different, they have different lengths.